# Whether to apply business rules on C# code or save in database?

Tags: c#, database, business-logic

I have developed a E-commerce application which contains complex rules like catalog pricing rules etc.
I saved the rules on database. I am confused whether to calculate the rules on code or on database using stored procedures.

Comment: @lti you already have rules in database, just go for stored procedures

Comment: I also down-voted. It's not clear what you're asking at all. What rules? What code? What DB structure? How are you currently connecting to the DB?

Comment: @DeeMac: Really that matters? As I am asking a general question, that what can be the best practice. This is simply being rude to a naive coder. :(

Comment: @Rex: Thanks a lot, I hope I get more views and I can decide

Comment: @ItiTyagi - you know clarity matters, so why are you even asking? I'm 'rude' for down-voting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally I would move logic into the client - databases are the expensive part to scale and them doing less means less licensing if it becomes better, plus the ways to TEST code in the database is harder (unit testing) and slower. I would do calcualtions on the client and store the results. There are (few) exceptions, but that is the general answer.

Comment: databases are the expensive part to scale and them doing less means less licensing if it becomes better-Please explain this one

Comment: @ItiTyagi Check the prices of Oracle or Sql server. Cores cost MONEY. Lots of - you can easily put another application server up for the cost of a single core of a high end database. Also, databases are hard to scale - sharding has steep requirements. Scaling application servers is a lot easier. My largest system had database servers for about 800.000 USD each. Imagine how much front level processing power we could have purchased for that money.

Comment: I agree, and I get this completely now. Accepted and voted the answer. :)

Comment: It's more nuanced. a procedure that process a few where clauses is cheaper than responding to a heavy pull query that locks the database. in some cases passing the data outside of the database for processing produce an additional security risk.